# Adding multiple sections in Crystal Reports without using subreports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm making a check report and need the check stub to show up twice on each page. I think i can do this by showing the same group header, details and footer on the same page twice. The issue I'm having is that the table I'm connecting too only stores the data for a brief moment while the report is being accessed which seems to bar me from using subreports. The subreports just show up blank. Is there a way to show the same section twice without using a subreport?

Comment: create a section b for each one and add same fields, like mirroring each section, GHa - GHb, Da - Db and GFa - GFb

Comment: you need to be more specific with your requirement.. you can show the same section twice but what is your requrirement and what do you want to show in the section and why it can't be achieved by sub reports.